# Ordenar array segun condicion

Tags: javascript

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con javascript vanilla y quiero ordenar numeros dentro de un array con un orden especifico.

por ejemplo:
`(5, 4, 9, 3, 9, 9] → [9, 4, 5, 3, 9, 9]`

donde el numero 4 siempre debe de estar seguido de un 5. solo intercambiado de lugar con el numero que esta despues del 4, 9 en este ejemplo.

he intentado esto:

```js
const arrayprueba = [1, 4, 1, 7, 5, 3, 1];
const orden45 = (array) => {
  let position4;
  let position5;

  array.forEach((num, index) => {
    if (num == 5) {
      position5 = index;
    }
    if (num == 4) {
      position4 = index;
    }

    if (position4 < position5) {
      let remplazado = array[position4 + 1];
      array.splice(position4 + 1, 1, array[position5]);
      array.splice(position5, 1, remplazado);
    }
    if (position4 > position5) {
      let remplazado = array[position4 + 1];
      array.splice(position4 + 1, 1, array[position5]);
      array.splice(position5, 1, remplazado);
    }
  });
  return array;
};

console.log(orden45(arrayprueba));
```

Pero al insertar arrays mas largos y con mas numero por ordenar deja de funcionar
ejemplo este:
[5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5];

Comment: cual es la logica para llegar a esa orden

Comment: Que sentido tiene este ordenamiento tan raro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algoritmo**

- Se propone tener tener dos arreglos que guardarán las posiciones (índices) de los números 4 y 5. Estas posiciones se irán actualizando conforme a se vayan usando, es decir, el arreglo "`fours`" contendrá los índices de los números 4 que no estén seguidos de un 5; por otra parte, el arreglo "`fives`" contendrá los índices de los números 5 que estén disponibles.
- Se recorre el arreglo de números (iterador `i`) hasta la penúltima posición

  - Si el elemento `i` es igual a 5 se evalúa si hay un número 4 al cuál al que no le sigue un número 5 (o sea, si el arreglo `fours` tiene más de 0 elementos):

    - Si es así, se intercambian las posiciones `fours[0] + 1` y la posición `i`
    - De lo contrario, se guarda la posición `i` en `fives`, indicando que hay un 5 disponible
  - Si el elemento `i` es igual a 4, se evalúa si `fives` tiene más de 0 elementos (si hay cincos disponibles) y si el siguiente número no es 5.

    - Si es así, se intercambian las posiciones `fives[0]` e `i + 1`. Se incrementa `k` en 1 para no marcar la siguiente iteración como un 5 disponible; además se elimina la posición `fives[0]` indicando que esa posición ya no está disponible (ya fue usada)
    - De lo contrario, se guarda la posición `i` en `fours`, indicando que hay un 4 pendiente
- Finalmente, se compara si el último elemento es 4 y hay cincos disponibles. Si es así, entonces se sustrae el elemento 5 y se coloca al final del arreglo.

```js
let numbers = [5, 4, 9, 3, 4, 5, 9, 5, 5, 9, 4, 6, 4];
let fours = [];
let fives = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; ++i) {
    
    if (numbers[i] === 5) {
        if (fours.length > 0){
            numbers[i] = numbers[fours[0] + 1];
            numbers[fours.shift() + 1] = 5;
            
        } else
            fives.push(i);
            
    } else if (numbers[i] === 4) {
        if (fives.length > 0 && numbers[i + 1] !== 5) {
            numbers[fives.shift()] = numbers[i + 1];
            numbers[i + 1] = 5;
            ++i;
        } else
            fours.push(i);
        
    }
}

if (fives.length > 0 && numbers[numbers.length - 1] === 4){
    numbers.splice(fives[0], 1);
    numbers.push(5);
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Lo siento, tenía un typo en un push, ya hice la edición,, sólo era cambiar los corchetes por paréntesis

Answer (score 1):

Quise escribir una función más breve:

```js
console.log(sortorden45([1, 4, 1, 7, 5, 3, 1]).toString());
console.log(sortorden45([5, 4, 9, 3, 9, 9]).toString());
console.log(sortorden45([5, 4, 9, 3, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 4, 6, 4]).toString());


function sortorden45(array) {
  const [...arr] = array;
  const map = (n, i) => ({ n, i });
  const filterA = N => ({ n }) => n === N;
  const filterB = (N, offset) => ({ n, i }) => arr[i + offset] !== N;
  const _4s = arr.map(map).filter(filterA(4)).filter(filterB(5, 1));
  const _5s = arr.map(map).filter(filterA(5)).filter(filterB(4, -1));
  _4s.forEach(({ i }, j) => i > arr.length - 2
    ? [arr[i], arr[_5s[j].i]] = [arr[_5s[j].i], arr[i]]
    : [arr[i + 1], arr[_5s[j].i]] = [arr[_5s[j].i], arr[i + 1]]);
  return arr;
}
```